# Retrieve Userid from a claims in a cookie in Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc, claims-based-identity

I want to store a userId in a cookie, in ASP.NET Core MVC. Where can I access it?

**Login:**

```
var claims = new List<Claim> {
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "testUserId")
};

var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "webuser");
var userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);
HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("Cookie", userPrincipal,
    new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        AllowRefresh = false
    });
```

**Logout:**

```
User.Identity.GetUserId(); // <-- 'GetUserId()' doesn't exists!?

ClaimsPrincipal user = User;
var userName = user.Identity.Name; // <-- Is null.

HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("Cookie");
```

**It's possible in MVC 5 ------------------->**

**Login:**

```
// Create User Cookie
var claims = new List<Claim>{
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, webUser.Sid)
    };

var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
authenticationManager.SignIn(
    new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        AllowRefresh = true // TODO 
    },
    new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie)
);
```

**Get UserId:**

```
public ActionResult TestUserId()
{
    IPrincipal iPrincipalUser = User;
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId(); // <-- Working
}
```

**Update - Added screenshot of the Claims which are null -------**

`userId` is also `null`.

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should be able to get it via the HttpContext:

```
var userId = context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
```

In the example *context* is the HttpContext.

The Startup.cs (just the basics as in the template website):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseIdentity();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: Will test later. But I'm pretty sure I tryed "User.Claims" which are "null". I don't know why though :)

Comment: It's also null. I'm sure your line is correct, but I must need something else I guess. Like something in StartUp.cs I have not added yet. ASP.NET Core MVC is new to me, so I might not have added all nesessary dependencies, for Claims to work.

Comment: See added Screenshot :)

Comment: and logout is a controller action? Maybe the user is already logged out? Is the value available after you logged in?

Comment: Yes it's another Action. I have to the logic in another Action, before I can poke into the cookie. At least that's the way it was in MVC 5 when I made it there, if I remembered correct.

Comment: put a breakpoint in it, maybe the action is visited twice: the first time the user is still logged in, but the second time it's logged out and the cookie is cleared.

Comment: It's not that. I have a breakpoint and just below in the logiutbaction i call SignOutAsync(). Could you add your StartUp.cs to your answer?

Comment: I have claims but don't know how to store in cookie

Answer (score 9):

Using [FindFirst](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159730(v=vs.110).aspx) method from [ClaimsPrincipal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

`var userId = context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;`